# Concatenate columns D and C using macro

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010, concatenation

Could you please help in concatenating cells using Excel 2010 macro. I have columns A to E. I want to concatenate columns D and C in column F. Please note that I don't know the exact number of rows in column D and C but the macro should stop concatenating when there are no values in the said columns. Sample:

```
A     B      C           D         E         F
0   Exist   Echalas    Gerald     25256    Gerald Echalas
```

....

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out, from MSDN, it has an example for going through each row.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213477

Their sample:

```
Sub ConcatColumns()

Do While ActiveCell <> ""  'Loops until the active cell is blank.

  'The "&" must have a space on both sides or it will be
  'treated as a variable type of long integer.

  ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = _
     ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1) & " " & ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)

  ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Good point. Noted. Although you have done exactly what you are notifying me of :P

Comment: tnx.i tried this one but i dont know how offset works. its looping until the end of the rows eventhough there was no value.

Comment: If I get some time later this evening I'll try and give you a better explanation. .offset offsets from the currently selected row. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa613022(v=office.10).aspx

Comment: Although it should be noted that if you plan to add columns in the future, this would overwrite them and you should use something similar to Manh Ly's `cells(row, FINAL COLUMN INDEX HERE) = cells(row, FIRST HALF OF CONCAT INDEX) & " " & and cells(row, SECOND HALF OF CONCAT INDEX)`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this (untested)

```
dim row as integer
row = 1
while(cells(row, 3) <> "" and cells(row, 4) <> "" 
    cells(row, 5) = cells(row, 3) & " " & and cells(row, 4) 
    row = row + 1
wend
```

Answer (score 1):

This will combine values columns C, D to F as "D, C" regardless of gaps up to the last used row.

```
Sub CombineCols()
    Dim oWS As Worksheet, lLastRow As Long, r As Long

    Set oWS = ActiveSheet
    lLastRow = oWS.Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row
    For r = 1 To lLastRow
        ' Combine if both C and D are not empty
        If Len(oWS.Cells(r, 3)) > 0 And Len(oWS.Cells(r, 4)) > 0 Then
            oWS.Cells(r, 6).Value = oWS.Cells(r, 4).Value & " " & oWS.Cells(r, 3).Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You can change the check condition so that it does not require both valid text is columns C and D to combine.

Tip: You can reference the column of a cell with long number - starting from A=1.

Comment: I found this very helpful for a similar problem I had. Thanks a lot. Your code is perfect and  is generic as it considers the right condition for the for loop. Kudos to you...

Answer (score 0):

Lets say u r in sheet1

```
Sub test()
Dim r As Range
Dim lr As Integer
With Sheets("Sheet1")
lr = .Range("C500000").End(xlUp).Row

For Each r In .Range("F2:F" & lr)

r.Value = r.Offset(0, -2).Value & " " & r.Offset(0, -3).Value

Next r

End With

End Sub
```

Tested

Comment: Thank you all...The macro is already working:)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good job for a formula

```
Sub ConcatName()

    With ActiveSheet
        .Range("F1").Resize(.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[-2]&"" ""&RC[-3]"
    End With

End Sub
```

The CurrentRegion property gets the blob of data around A1, extends F1 by the number of rows, then inserts a formula that concatenates.

Answer (score 0):

The concatenate function is quite easy to implement in a Macro. All you do is place an '&' between objects you would like to concatenate. In your case is would look like this:

```
Range("F1").Value = Range("C1").Value & " " & Range("D1")
```

*Note that I added a space between the C1 and D1 values

Next you are going to need a loop to iterate through your data. There are several good methods for controlling when the loop will stop.

**Method #1**

The simplest method is to not worry about when the macro stops. This may work in your case be concatenating nothing with nothing yields nothing.

```
loop
    Range("F1").Value = Range("C1").Value & " " & Range("D1")
next
```

**Method #2**

End the loop when a specified column runs out of data. In your case this could look like:

```
While(Range("A" & i).value <> "")
    Range("F1").Value = Range("C1").Value & " " & Range("D1")
    i = i + 1 
Wend
```

**Method #3**

Excel has a function (.count) that will return the number of entries in a column (will not work correctly if there are gaps). Use the value return along with a for loop to stop the loop when there is no more data.